# Add multiple classes in ngClass using string concatenation

Tags: angular, ng-class

I am trying to add multiple classes in ngClass, where one of the classes is a concatenation of a literal string and a variable. This is what I need, but I got a syntax error:

```
<div [ngClass]="[{'w-' + percentage}, {'finished': true}]"></div>
```

Where is the error in this expression?

Comment: `<div [ngClass]="{'w-' + percentage: true, 'finished': true}"></div>`

Comment: Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 7 in [{'w-' + percentage: true, 'finished': true}]

Comment: remove [] brackets from *[{'w-' + percentage: true, 'finished': true}]*, only curly braces allowed.

Comment: Parser Error: Missing expected : at column X in [{'w-' + percentage, 'finished': true}]

Comment: please write like @enno.void suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div [ngClass]="'w-' + percentage" [class.finished]="true/false"></div>
```

or if class *finished* is not connected to any variable then:

```
<div class="finished" [ngClass]="'w-' + percentage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this, It will resolve your problem.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'w-' + percentage: true, 'finished': true}"></div>
```